# How convert type of value in Visual Prolog 8?

Tags: prolog, type-conversion, visual-prolog

I need convert string to ACII add 1 and convert back.

```
Next_letter = convert(char, convert(integer, Letter) + 1)
```

But error:

> main.pro(19,48) error c504 : The expression has type 'main::letter',
>   which is incompatible with the type '::integer'

Full program :

```
   /* программа prog2_8.pro */
/* генерации ряда букв а…d в столбик в порядке возрастания */

implement main
    open core, console

domains
    letter = string.

class predicates
    write_letter : (letter).
clauses
    write_letter("e").

    write_letter(Letter) :-
        Letter < "e",
        write("   ", Letter),
        nl,
        Next_letter = convert(char, convert(integer, Letter) + 1),
        write_letter(Next_letter).

    run() :-
        write("letters:"),
        nl,
        write_letter("a"),
        fail().

    run() :-
        nl,
        write("Press Enter"),
        _ = readchar(),
        succeed().

end implement main

goal
    console::runUtf8(main::run).
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following using `char_int/2`:

```
char_int(Letter, IntLetter),        % Letter = 'a' -> IntLetter = 97
NextIntLetter = IntLetter + 1,      % NextIntLetter = 98
char_int(NextLetter, NextIntLetter) % NextLetter = 'b'
```

And here `NextLetter` should be what you need

---

### From VIP documentation

> **char_int**(CHAR *CharArg*, INTEGER *IntArg*)
>
> **Flow patterns**      (i, o), (o, i), (i, i)
>
> Convert between characters and their ASCII values
>
> **Remarks**
>
> (i, o)    Binds *IntArg* to the ASCII code for *CharArg*.
>   (o, i)    Binds *CharArg* to the character having the ASCII code specified by *IntArg*
>   (notice that it takes into account only the lower byte of an integer
>   value).
>   (i, i)    Succeeds if *IntArg* is bound to the ASCII code for
>   *CharArg*; fails if it is not.
>
> **Fail**
>
> See remarks for (i, i).
>
> **Errors**
>
> No errors.
>
> **Example**
>
> To test this example use "Project | Test Goal" in Visual Prolog VDE.
>
> ```
> GOAL:
>     char_int('a',X) 
>     X=97 
>     1 Solution
>
> GOAL:
>     char_int(X,97) 
>     X=a 
>     1 Solution
>
> GOAL:
>     char_int('a',97) 
>     Yes
>
> GOAL:
>     char_int('a',197) 
>     No
> ```

---

**Edit**

Your problem is that a `string` can not be converted in its *ASCII value* as it is a **set of characters**. You have to replace `letter = string` with `letter = char` and `"` (around your characters) with `'`.